# How do I prevent my smoke simulation from getting smaller with more resolution divisions?

Tags: physics, mantaflow

Whenever I increase the resolution divisions, the smoke always becomes smaller. I want more resolution without shrinking its size.
[image]

Comment: Um… can you demonstrate with a screenshot? My best guess is that you’re mistaking lower resolution being blocky and unable to fit properly around the source for greater intended smoke output. You can increase the “distance from mesh” setting on the smoke emitter to make it output smoke from a larger margin around it’s surface, though.

Comment: Yes, screenshot added!

Comment: I don’t know how you made a smoke simulation look like that, but yeah, that looks pretty much like what I thought.